# Create Wordpress Menu Item Without Linking to a Custom Page

Tags: admin, admin-menu, add-menu-page

With add_menu_page there is a required option to add a menu slug that leads to a admin page.  I wish to create a custom admin item, but not one that links to another page (I have other plans for the menu item).

Is this possible to do?  If so, any idea how?

Comment: And what are you planning to do with it?

Comment: I want to use css/javascript to create sections in the wordpress admin section.  When i click on a link, certain menu items will appear (and others will disappear).  For example, I'd like to create a Content Section under which all the various post types appear (Posts, Pages, CPT).  Click on the Content link and all the Post Types show up (and the other links do not)